# VerneMQ plugin_chain_exhausted Authentication MySQL

Tags: mysql, authorization, mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

I have a running instance of VerneMQ (cluster of 2 nodes) on Google kubernets and using MySQL (CloudSQL) for Auth. Server accepts connections over TLS

It works fine, but after a few days i start seeing this message on the log:

can't authenticate client {[],<<"Client-id">>} from X.X.X.X:16609 due to plugin_chain_exhausted

The client app (paho) complains that the server refused the connection for being "not authorized (code=5 in paho error)"

after a few retry it finally connects. but every time it get's harder and harder until it just won't connect anymore

If i restart VerneMQ everything get's back to normal

I have only 3 clients currently connected at most, at the same time.

clients already connected have no issues in pub/sub.

In my configuration i have (among other things):

```
log.console.level=debug
plugins.vmq_diversity=on
vmq_diversity.mysql.* = all of them set
allow_anonymous=off
vmq_diversity.auth_mysql.enabled=on
```

it's like the server degrades over time. the status webpage reports no problem

My verne server was build from the git repository about a month ago and runs on a docker container

what could be the cause?
what else could i check to find posibles causes? maybe a diversity missconfiguration?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

To quickly explain the `plugin_chain_exhausted` log: with Verne you can run multiple authentication/authorization plugins, and they will be checked in a chain. If one plugin allows the client, it will be in. If no plugin allows the client, you'll see the log above.

This does not explain the behaviour you describe, though. I don't think I have seen that.

In any case, the first thing to check is whether you actually run multiple plugins. For instance: have you disabled the vmq.passwd and the vmq.acl plugins?